# Isomorphic or not: two infinite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> The groups $(\mathbb{C}\setminus \left \{ 0 \right \},\cdot )$ and $(\mathbb{R},+)$ are not isomorphic.

So I was not clear whether this statement is true or not.

Comment: It's true, they are not : $\mathbb{C}^*$ is not uniquely divisible.

Comment: How many soultions has equation $x\cdot x=1$ got in $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$? How many solutions has equation $x+x=0$ got in $\Bbb R$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: one of these groups has (nonidentity) elements of finite order, but the other does not.